# Responsive Design - Android not Scaling

Tags: php, android, mysql, css, responsive-design

The responsive design I'm working through has presented another problem.  To keep it simple, I set the body to snap down to 480px if the screen size or device size is less than 750px.  Then, ideally, the screen on any device should scale to fit the width.

After some help here already today, I added the viewport meta, so now the CSS is responding to both my iPhone and Android, as well as the desktop browser when minimized.

The iPhone looks great; it zooms to the width, so even though the webpage is approx 480px, it fits perfectly into my 320px iPhone screen.

However, on the Android, it's zoomed in too far.  About 25%-30% of the right side is off the screen and I have to scroll over to see it.  If I pinch-to-zoom-out just a bit, then the window fits the screen width-wise and it looks fine.  I don't know why I have to manually zoom out though.

- Why is the Android not zooming out to the width of the page when the page is loaded?

My meta tag looks like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
@media all and (max-device-width: 750px), all and (max-width: 750px) {
  body {max-width:480px;}
  #container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    min-width:480px;
  }
  #rightnav {display:none;}
}
```

Comment: You should take a mobile first approach. Style your site to work at 320px wide and then change the design at 750px. This will ensure your site works perfectly on any screen smaller than 750px.

Comment: We're converting and existing legacy site.  Starting over with a mobile page just isn't close to practical unfortunately.  Plus the site is more than 320 pixels wide (there are 160 and a 300 pixle ad zones next to each other).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're planning to display a 480px layout on a 320px screen you obviously have to zoom, so this works exactly as specified, but the iphone "smartly" ignores some rules to display it fullscreen.
you can set the `initial-scale` value to 0.75 to force every device to keep that zoom level in the beginning. of course the better solution would be to have yet another media query to scale down the screen contents even more on 320px devices.

Comment: The main body of the page has 2 banner ads that have to remain.  One is 160 wide, one is 300 wide.  Together, these are 460 pixels of width that I must have....add in a little padding and such and that's the 480 pixels I'm dealing with.  So, I need the 480px to scale to 320 on the iphone and whatever it needs to on various andriod devices.